# Is integral operator surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the linear operator ${\rm A}$ given by $${\rm A}f(t) = \int_0^t  f(x)\ dx$$  onto? It would be onto if the range space of ${\rm A}$ is equal to whatever ${\rm A}$ is mapping to, but I am not even sure what ${\rm A}$ is mapping onto...

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in this form. Any function can be made sujective by restricting its codomain to the image of the domain under the function. So you need to specify the domain on which you want to consider $A$. But then just take the image of the domain and then your operator will be surjective.

Comment: @Dirk some use the term `operator` to indicate a linear map from a space into itself, in which case the context forbids restrictions of range.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking at an operator that maps C[0,1] to C[0,1]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the more relevant question in this context would be, in which domain are we working? If it's the space of infinitely differentiable functions $C^\infty[a,b]$, then the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us a positive answer.

More precisely, the fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integration fully characterize those functions that are given as an integral of another function as those which are [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions).

However, judging from your tags, you might be looking at a more common space, say the space of (piecewise?) continuous functions on some interval, in which case the answer is negative. Not every continuous function is absolutely continuous: the linked article contains some examples, the best suited for our needs might be $f(x):=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ over $[-1,1]$, say. To see why there exists no $g\in C[-1,1]$ such that $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$, show that a function defined by such an integral is absolutely continuous, then use the sequence $(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n)^{-1}$ to show $f$ isn't.

Comment: +1 but actually, A is the operator, not the range ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually looking at an operator that maps from C[0,1]->C[0,1]. Why would it not be surjective in this case?

Comment: @arbautjc fudge, you're right. Let me fix that.

Comment: @user129289021 the answer is, as I mentioned, that only absolutely continuous functions are given by such an integral, and that not every continuous function is absolutely continuous. I included an example from the linked article to help you see why.

Comment: Actually, $A$ is also not surjective on $C^\infty[0,1]$ since $Af(0) = 0$ (but otherwise this is the only obstruction). The same argument shows that $A$ is not sujective on $C[0,1]$.

Comment: A valid point, @Dirk, but as you say somewhat superficial (the image in $C^\infty[0,1]$ would have co-dimension $1$). The same cannot be said about $A$'s image in $C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

I Assume your function is from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$. Now look at set of all functions in $C[0,1]$  which is having a primitive. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_function